# How can I bind a list model which contains a complex type in MVC4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with input elements like this:

```
...
<input type="hidden" name="orders[0].ID" value="1">
<input type="text" name="orders[0].Name" value="Some name">
<input type="date" name="orders[0].Date" value="09/08/2014">
<input type="time" name="orders[0].Time" value="5:16 AM">
...
<input type="hidden" name="orders[1].ID" value="2">
<input type="text" name="orders[1].Name" value="Some name2">
<input type="date" name="orders[1].Date" value="09/08/2014">
<input type="time" name="orders[1].Time" value="5:16 AM">
...
<input type="hidden" name="orders[2].ID" value="2">
<input type="text" name="orders[2].Name" value="Some name2">
<input type="date" name="orders[2].Date" value="09/08/2014">
<input type="time" name="orders[2].Time" value="5:16 AM">
...
```

So, when the form submits it should bind to an action like this:

```
public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<Order> orders){}
```

The thing is, my view has the **date** and the **time** as separate input elements, but the Order class has one single **DateTime** property, which should combine the two.  Is there any way to bind this in a way that is simpler than creating a new Modelbinder?

Comment: Easiest way to do it is to just create a DTO such as a ViewModel for the Order class and put the logic in there

Comment: You need to go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials, in particular how to use html helpers to bind to properties of your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript to handle onsubmit event and merge data from those two fields into one that will be parsed as DateTime. Do you need some code to see how it could be done?